# How can I navigate until a span into a table?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to know how I can navigate to a span within a table; this is my code

[image]

This is html code is produced by a visualforce page. In my pageblocktable the id of my table is `id="maintable"`. I want to select a span in the first row of the table, using jQuery, but I cannot.

Comment: Please post the actual HTML mark-up (in *text*, not in pictures). Also, explain what you're having difficulty with?

Comment: Hi david, i have some difficulties to post the html. Can you explain me how? Thanks, Fabrizio

Comment: Without knowing what difficulties you're facing, it's difficult to provide help; but I'd suggest taking a look over at the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and see if that solves the problem, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

CSS descendant selector:

```
$('#maintable span')
```

This will return all spans inside the table. You can loop through then using

```
$('#maintable span').each(function (i) {
     // do something here
});
```

or, if you need just the very first one, use:

```
$('#maintable span').first()
```

or

```
$('#maintable span:first')
```

**EDIT**:

For the first row use

```
$('#maintable tr:first span:first')
```